# Error with "rvm requirements"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to run "rvm requirements" it fails, giving me following error:

```
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system....
Installing required packages: libksba.....
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install libksba',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/Hany/.rvm/log/1398501597/package_install_libksba.log
+ case "$1" in
+ [[ -t 1 ]]
+ return 1
+ printf %b 'There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation\n'
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation
+ case "$_system_version" in
+ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

I thought I would use homebrew to install individually. So I ran "brew install libksba"

```
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libksba/libksba-1.3.0.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libksba-1.3.0.tar.bz2
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libksba/1.3.0
==> make install
make[2]: *** [reader.lo] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [asn1-parse.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
```

But this failed, saying it was already installed. Very confused here. Any help?

Comment: I think you have to install homebrew

Comment: have you tried `brew tap --repair`?